# Emacs auto-complete-c-headers. Symbol's value as variable is void

Tags: c++, c, emacs, autocomplete

I am using Emacs 24.3, on Windows 7. I installed `auto-complete-mode` and `autocomplete-c-headers` with ELPA.

To `.emacs` I added:

```
(require 'auto-complete)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20140208.653")    ; This may not be appeared if you have already added.
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20140208.653/dict")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)

;|---------------------------------------------------------------+
;|auto-complete c/c++ headers
;|---------------------------------------------------------------+
(add-to-list 'load-path   
         "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-c-headers-20140325.835") 
(defun my:ac-c-headers-init ()
  (require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'aсhead:include-directories '"d:/DevTools/env/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include")
)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-headers-init)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-headers-init)
```

When I run in C++-mode, it shows the error

```
Symbol's value as variable is void
```

Comment: switch to your .cpp file and use M-: to evaluate (debug (c++-mode t)), this will open up the debugger on the error and hopefully tell you which variable is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First locate C/C++ headers on your computer by running the following command.

`gcc -xc++ -E -v -`

On my ArchLinux they are located here

`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../include/c++/4.9.1
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../include/c++/4.9.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../include/c++/4.9.1/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include-fixed
 /usr/include`

Then the complete C/C++ auto-completion which works for me is this.

`;; C++ auto completion mode
(require 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
;a function which initializes auto-complete-c-headers and get called for c/c++ hooks
(defun my:acc-c-header-init ()
  (require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'achead:include-directories '" /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../include/c++/4.9.1
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../include/c++/4.9.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../include/c++/4.9.1/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include-fixed
 /usr/include"
     )
  )`

Try that.

Comment: Yes, I've done this way. Your comment is little late, hovever thanks.